# How to allign text in android Webview?

Tags: android, html, textview

I am displaying a html code in webView. can anybody tell me how to allign text in that HTMl to both left and right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/al1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="About Us : Work Under Progress.."
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:textColor="#ff000000"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="0px">
</TextView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried gravity right and left?

Comment: what do you mean with left and right? left and right at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, I meant left OR right. Not both at the same time. I'm not even sure what that would do. android:gravity="left" should align left

Comment: @ Janusz: yes, I want both right and left alinged text.

Comment: Both left and right? Justify?

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code

```
<TextView>
```

...
   android:gravity="right"
   ...

```
</TextView>
```

Comment: Just a little note, android:gravity="right" should be inside your <TextView> tag.

Comment: I mean, you have to put it inside the tag, not between the tags. Like this: <TextView android:gravity="right">